# Why are values squared in distance formulas, such as the Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Why do you square the values in the Pythagorean Theorem or any distance formula wherein you're trying to find the distance between two points in two-dimensional, Euclidean space?

for example, why are we squaring the difference in the two $x,x$ values and two $y,y$ values?

$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$

Comment: you think of this by considering the proof of Pythagoras theorem by taking squares on the sides of the triangle and if you can find the combination you can apply this to the distance formula

Answer (score 2):

This GIF (jiff) is very instructive.

[image]